# How do I get NM cable to an exterior junction box on the gable end of a house from the attic?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I (in the US) know I can't use NM cable in wet locations. However, I'd like to bring power from a circuit that's running on NM cable in an attic to conduit on the exterior (gable end) of the house:

[image: gable end diagram]

I'm guessing I have to transition from NM to something else somewhere on the exterior of the house. Do I put a box on the interior of the attic? If so, do I run conduit from the knockout on the back of the exterior box to the back of the interior box? That's a really short piece of conduit (not sure how thick the siding is). Do I mount the interior box somewhere further away? Do I transition from the interior to conduit on the exterior in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Nah. You don't have to do that. Most inspectors allow you to bring Romex out through a wall and straight into the back of a bell box. Make sure you put a bead of clear silicone around the box and drill a small hole (no large than 1/4") into the bottom of the box for drainage.

Also, FYI, depending on the width of your overhang, and how close you are to the soffit, it may not be a wet area, but rather a damp area. For example, the area under a covered porch is a damp area. You can use non while in use covers for receptacles.

Basically, if it's not subject to direct rainfall, you're not wet. But regardless, most inspectors allow Romex to poke through the wall.

Answer (score 0):

A box outside the house often counts as a wet location and a "by the book" interpretation says you can't bring NM cable into that box. But like the rule that every GFCI-protected receptacle must have a sticker stating the same, inspectors routinely turn a blind eye to violations of this. You're likely to be forgiven for running NM from attic into that box on the exterior of the gable.

If you want to do it by the book, though, you'll need to use wet-location wiring. One option is UF cable -- no conduit needed, but don't forget strain relief (a clamp of some sort) where the cable enters the j-box. UF is fine to use indoors too so it can cross the attic to wherever your source of power is located.

Supposing that exterior conduit is new work and you'll be buying wiring to go inside it too, I'd just use the same stuff for the part that crosses the attic. If that means using UF cable for the whole job, great. If you were planning THWN or similar conductors for the outside part then use that in the attic too: rather than making a transition on the inside of the gable, run conduit across the attic to wherever the circuit now exists. Then you can use the same THWN outdoors and through the attic.

Comment: FYI, there really is no such thing as THWN anymore. Modern THHN is dual rated THWN.